# Adjust height of top view when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-view, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to adjust height of textView when soft keyboard shows up? I wish not to reposition textView but instead shrink its height when the keyboard shows as a user taps on enter your response field. Whereas textfield should move up to above the keyboard.

[image]

Edit:

I would say the iOS equivalent would be to detect the keyboard show up event and then adjusting the layout constraint according to the keyboard height..

Comment: You looking for an attribute on AndroidManifest (at Activity tag) like ```android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"```

Comment: oh I've tried that. But that wouldnt resize the height of that textView 
edit: This does move up the textField but I also need the height of textView to resize accordingly

Comment: That depends on the Layout of the view, it supports being resized (by using only relative constraints and not a fixed size such height = 128dp)?

Comment: Yup wow that worked wonderfully! Cant believe I missed that out

Comment: Added as answer by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looking for an attribute on AndroidManifest (at Activity tag) like `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Make sure that the Layout of the view supports being resized, by using only relative constraints and NOT a fixed size such `android:height = 128dp`.